# URL Naming Convention with Repetitive Letter

Tags: web-services, naming-standards, url

What is a good practice to name an URL if it contains repetitive letters. For example, `/info/foossite`

The two **s** looks kind of odd and if this was access point for a `Web-Service`, this could lead into misspelling. In most programming languages, we have `Camel` notation. However, as URLs are case insensitive, we don't have that luxury here.

So, what is the best practice in this regard?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I dont think its a big deal to have duplicated letters.  But if you are concerned it will cause confusion or misspellings, you might use a dash in between the words, like `/info/foos-site`.

Comment: That would be fine for composite words, but not for words like "classes"--> "clas-ses".

Comment: There'd be no reason to be concerned with words such as 'classes'.  Thats the way they are supposed to be spelled.

Answer (score 3):

HTTP URIs are **not** case-insensitive. The host is case-insensitive, but the path is case-sensitive (see [STD 66](http://tools.ietf.org/html/std66#section-6.2.2.1)). Check these two HTTP URIs, for example:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow

You’ll find that they represent different pages.

So you could use camel case URIs, e.g. `example.net/FoosSite`. (Note that maybe some servers, probably those running on Microsoft operating systems, treat all HTTP URIs as case-insensitive by default, so you’d have to check their documentation.)

But in my opinion there is no need for camel case. If your path contains several words, you <s>should</s> could use a delimiter of some kind. Probably most popular is `-`. Wikipedia uses `_`. You can find many discussions about which delimiter to use for SEO and usability. See for example [this (closed) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119312/urls-dash-vs-underscore) or an [(older) blog post by Matt Cutts (who is working for Google)](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/dashes-vs-underscores/).

Answer (score 2):

GrandmasterB's solution is sufficient, but I present an alternative if you're using a RESTful web service.  The whole point behind being RESTful is to make a URL read intuitively.  The first part of the URL is the subject of the pages.

In other words in the URL:

`http://www.host.com/books/1`

`books` would be the subject.  However, there's no reason why you shouldn't be able to have URLs like:

`http://www.host.com/foos/site/1`

So long as it makes sense that they're separate words  (i.e. please don't make URLs like `http://www.host.com/book/keeper/1`), I wouldn't have any problems doing it this way.